# Load external Python files on the web

Tags: python

In JavaScript, we could use `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.cdn.com/first.js"></script>` to load external javascript files on the web.

I am wondering how to load external Python files on the web in a local Python program?

Comment: Read about installing packages from other sources https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/. Read up documentation for those external packages to learn how to use them. Typically *import <package>* imports the package into your program namespace.

Comment: that means we have to do "pip install"?